# How do I unpause qbqbqb on android?

Tags: qbqbqb

I've just started playing qbqbqb, and while it seems like the game works alright with touch controls, I run into an issue whenever the games pauses.

Whenever the game pauses, either  through app switching or other means, I get this screen:

[image: "Paused. use arrows or gamepad to unpause. press escape (keyboard) or start (gamepad) to exit"]

Unfortunately, I have neither arrow keys nor a gamepad connected, so I'm not sure what to do to unpause the game.

When I press the in-game back button, I go back to the level select menu.
And when I press the "hardware" back button, it asks if I want to exit the game.

**So how do I unpause the game?**

Comment: Interesting. When I switch back into qbqbqb on Android, it starts immediately, without remaining paused.

Answer (score 1):

After a while of searching I turned up nothing. After searching on the Review site (http://www.androidrundown.com/app-rundown/qbqbqb-review/) and on a bunch of third party sites. I came to this conclusion.

"It's a nice bug". Try to re-install the app.